# Crystal report subreport orientation VB6

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, report, subreport

I am creating a report in VB6, in particular I have a main report with landscape orientation, then I insert a subreport again with landscape orientation but when I print it the sub-report appears to be portrait cuttig some data.

I set the printer properties orientation to both report and subreport.

Any idea on the reasons?

Thanks in advance,
giampaolo

Answer (score 0):

If you go to **Format Subreport ...**, **Can Grow** should be checked. Also make sure the fields in the subreport are marked can grow.

Comment: Tanks Jak, I checked but  all the fields in the subreport are marked as can grow, I checked also the printer orientation during the execution and it is set to landscape but the sub-report is print portrait.

Comment: I solved setting in the datail format of the main report and in the ReportStart of the subreport the printwidth parameter. I don't know why but setting them at design time the report is printed in portrait mode while setting them at runtime the report is printed in landscape.